# Using numbers AND letters in switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am wanting to make a simple thing where I can use the "q" key to quit my program. I am not sure if it is even possible as my searches are not giving me both, just one or the other.

```
    int var = in.nextInt();

        switch (var)
        {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter num");
                long num = in.nextLong();                  
                a.getPrime(num);
                break;
            case "q":
                System.out.println("Thanks for using");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
```

As you can see, I have var set to get an integer, which obviously can't take letters. Is there some way to get this done or do I have to just deal with it?

Comment: If you want to take characters as input, then you should use char as input not number, how the code will know the entered number is q??

Comment: Read a`String ` and change the first case to "1"?

Comment: @AbhishekGautam I completely understand that. I want to know how to use both characters AND integers

Comment: @daniu Jeez I'm an idiot.. oh the downvotes I will get...

Comment: char c = reader.nextChar(); use this and make every switch case conditions as 'a' , '6' , 'q' .. and save your questions from down votes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `switch` statement can only operate on one variable, of one type, at a given time.  You may try prompting the user for a string:

```
String var = in.next();

switch(var) {
    case "1":
        System.out.println("Enter num");
        long num = in.nextLong();                  
        a.getPrime(num);
        break;

    case "q":
        System.out.println("Thanks for using");
        System.exit(0);
        break;

    default:
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change code

```
    String var = in.nextLine();

    switch (var)
    {
        case "1":
            System.out.println("Enter num");
            long num = in.nextLong();                  
            a.getPrime(num);
            break;
        case "q":
            System.out.println("Thanks for using");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String var = in.next();

    switch (var)
    {
        case "1":
            System.out.println("Enter num");
            long num = in.nextLong();                  
            a.getPrime(num);
            break;
        case "q":
            System.out.println("Thanks for using");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but just in case

```
public static void main(String...strings) throws IOException {  
        getValidInput();
    }

    private static void getValidInput() throws IOException {
        //Enter data using BufferReader 
        BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));        
        // Reading data using readLine 
        String input = reader.readLine(); 
        // Printing the read line 
        System.out.println("Entered String is :: "+input);   
        switch (input)
        {
        case "q":
            System.out.println("Thanks for using");
            System.exit(0);
        default:
            if(input.matches("[0-9]*")){
                int num = Integer.parseInt(input);                  
                System.out.println("Is Number Prime :: "+isPrime(num));
            }else{
                System.out.println("Enter a valid number");
            }
            getValidInput();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {  
        if (n <= 1) {  
            return false;  
        }  
        for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {  
            if (n % i == 0) {  
                return false;  
            }  
        }  
        return true;  
    }
```